# Changing Directory Names in a Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

I'm relatively new to Rails as well as using PassengerPhusion. I am running an Ubuntu server on Azure, and have [the demo app that Passenger provides working fine](http://fleetpro.cloudapp.net/).   I've even changed the text on the homepage.

My question is this:

In my directory, the file directory's name for the app is `passenger-ruby-rails-demo`  and while I am experimenting, i am changing the name of the directory to something like   `passenger-ruby-rails-demo-test`  and it returns an error message when viewing [fleetpro.cloudapp.net](http://fleetpro.cloudapp.net/).

I've tried looking through files trying to figure out how this is routed but haven't had any luck. Is there a file within the Rails installation that is telling Passenger to be inside the specific `passenger-ruby-rails-demo` directory? Pretty newbish question, but it is really bothering me!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about *how* the naming convention works in regards to the root directory name of your app "passenger-ruby-rails-demo", but I believe the name of that directory is important to running your Rails app, and might have to do something with the name of the module in your `config/application.rb` file which is named after your Rails app.

There is a solution though: use `gem rename`.

Add `gem rename` to your `Gemfile` and run `bundle install`.

Then *in **your app's root** directory*, run this:

```
rails g rename:app_to New-Name
```

This will basically "clone" the app with your new name. You may have to check to make sure all your config files are present afterwards, but from my experience using it, it was a quick breeze. You will most definitely have to push the new renamed app back to git or Azure.

**EDIT**

As an example I renamed a Rails app to show what you could expect from the output after running the command:

[image]

Comment: cool, thanks! I'll give that a try and see what i come up with

Comment: Not a problem, I originally said "do it in a different" directory, but I just tested it out now, and you should actually do it in the same directory. It will rename your app instead of cloning a second copy.

Comment: I finally got around to running the command, and just about everything worked.. So close! http://fleetpro.cloudapp.net/   So, it seems I have more investigating to do.. Rails successfully renamed the app, but something is broken

Answer (score 0):

The Rails app's name isn't the problem, it's the `PassengerAppRoot` switch you'll be using:

```
PassengerAppRoot /path/to/your/app
```

Rails doesn't actually care which folder it's put into, so *renaming Rails **won't** fix your problem*.

Renaming Rails only changes the internal class references within your application (things like `Rails.application.name` which have very subtle implications for your app).

In your Azure server, you'll need to locate either your `.htaccess` / `httpd.conf` / `nginx.conf` file, and change the `PassengerAppRoot` to your new path. This should resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks! I'm having a very difficult time finding the nginx.conf file